# Back arrow stays unmirrored in RTL layouts

Tags: ios, localization, right-to-left

I used the code bellow to adapt my app for RTL languages but the back button arrow stays unmirrored unlike other components.

code:

```
if ([NSLocale characterDirectionForLanguage:languageCode] == NSLocaleLanguageDirectionRightToLeft) {
     if ([[[UIView alloc] init] respondsToSelector:@selector(setSemanticContentAttribute:)]) {
        [[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute: UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft];
     }
}
else {

    if ([[[UIView alloc] init] respondsToSelector:@selector(setSemanticContentAttribute:)]) {
        [[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can make this works for back button arrow too?

Comment: Did u find any solution on this?

Comment: @Ameer Unfortunately no.